# prometheus query for continuous uptime

Tags: metrics, prometheus, continuous

I'm a prometheus newbie and have been trying to figure out the right query to get the last continuous uptime for my service.

For example, if the present time is 0:01:20 my service was up at 0:00:00, went down at 0:01:01 and went up again at 0:01:10, I'd like to see the uptime of "10 seconds".

I'm mainly looking at the "up{}" metric and possibly combine it with the functions (changes(), rate(), etc.) but no luck so far.  I don't see any other prometheus metric similar to "up" either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you need something which tells when your service was actually up vs. whether the node was up :)
We use the following (I hope one will help or the general idea of each):
1. When we look at a host we use `node_time{...} - node_boot_time{...}`
2. When we look at a specific process / container (docker via cadvisor in our case) we use `node_time{...} - on(instance) group_right container_start_time_seconds{name=~"..."}) by(name,instance)`

Comment: Thanks for defining the problem, that helped.  I was able to come up with a query that goes something like "time() - process_start_time{service="service-x"}" which seems to return my desired value.

Comment: ur welcome, feel free to upvote / mark the answer as correct for it to be more available for other with similar issues :)

Answer (score 0):

The following PromQL query must be used for calculating the application uptime in seconds:

```
time() - process_start_time_seconds
```

This query works for all the applications written in [Go](https://go.dev/), which use either [github.com/prometheus/client_golang](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/) or [github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics) client libraries, which expose the `process_start_time_seconds` metric by default. This metric contains unix timestamp for the application start time.

Kubernetes exposes the `container_start_time_seconds` metric for each started container by default. So the following query can be used for tracking uptimes for containers in Kubernetes:

```
time() - container_start_time_seconds{container!~"POD|"}
```

The `container!~"POD|"` filter is needed in order to filter aux time series:

- Time series with `container="POD"` label reflect e.g. `pause containers` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68744740/274937) for details.
- Time series without `container` label correspond to e.g. cgroups hierarchy. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328) for details.

If you need to calculate the overall per-target uptime over the given time range, then it is possible to estimate it with `up` metric. Prometheus automatically generates `up` metric per each scrape target. It sets it to `1` per each successful scrape and sets it to `0` otherwise. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/#automatically-generated-labels-and-time-series) for details. So the following query can be used for estimating the total uptime in seconds per each scrape target during the last 24 hours:

```
avg_over_time(up[24h]) * (24*3600)
```

See [avg_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg_over_time) docs for details.